# How to find string having single quote string from table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

Here is my input @Name as "Rupesh's"

I want to find 'Rupesh's' like name from the table '`AppliedPolicies`' table

```
Select PolicyID, CustomerName, PolicyDesc 
From AppliedPolicies 
Where PolicyDesc = @Name
```

Plz. suggest me how could i get the required result.

Comment: How did you declare the `@Name` variable?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Select PolicyID, CustomerName, PolicyDesc 
From AppliedPolicies 
Where PolicyDesc like '%' + @Name + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another single quote to escape the single quote in the name, i.e. 'Rupesh''s'

Example:

```
declare @name varchar(20) = 'Rupesh''s'

SELECT * FROM
AppliedPolicies
WHERE PolicyDesc = @Name
```

Comment: No problem, I figured you had the best answer. But it was not supported with an example. So I added one and upvoted. As far as I can tell the other answers misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select PolicyID, CustomerName, PolicyDesc From AppliedPolicies
Where PolicyDesc like'%Rupesh'
```

for more http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Answer (score 0):

According to your title, maybe try this:

```
  Select  
      PolicyID,  
      CustomerName,  
      PolicyDesc  
  From 
      AppliedPolicies  
  Where 
      PolicyDesc like '%''%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL

```
    Select PolicyID, CustomerName, PolicyDesc 
    From AppliedPolicies 
    Where Replace(PolicyDesc,'''','_') = Replace(**@Name**,'''','_')
```